# fuzzing xss mutillidae with OWASP ZAP

Tags: owasp, fuzzing, zap

I am playing with XSS fuzzing and find the zap proxy very good, since I am able to utilize the fuzz option. I don´t have burp pro, so I can´t import lists into repeater. My problem is that, I´m able to manually provoke a XSS response in the mutillidae webapp, but I cannot replicate it through the zap proxy. Which ultimately means that I´m not able to fuzz the parameter. I´ve tried fuzzing with queries I know works, and zap says they are reflected, but when I open the response in the browser, using the zap functionality to do so, there´s no brower pop-up. I´m able to provoke a pop-up using Burp suite, so I think it´s a feature of zap which prevents it. I have only experienced this with mutillidae. If someone has experienced the same and has a solution please explain. I have probably missed something obvious

Comment: There's no question here. However, just because a payload is reflected in a response doesn't mean there's an XSS. If you send the param/value pair `name=fred` and fred is in the response that's considered "Reflected" by the fuzzer. If you have a known good XSS payload put it in your fuzz list and see if the fuzzer considers it reflected (it should, though encoding/decoding etc may come into play). As for opening the response via ZAP it probably depends which functionality you're referring to (which you didn't specify). See: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/5025#issuecomment-426307926

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to tell you what exactly that little reflected symbol means. It doesn't necessarily mean that the payload was successful but rather that the payload you're trying to fuzz with was in the response. You need to manually see which payloads work and don't, you want to start with the payloads that have the reflected symbol. You said that you opened the response in your browser? Why are you doing that? You should be opening the request (instead of the response) that caused the response (AKA the alert box). Try this and see if the alert box pops up.

EDIT: Look at kingthorin's comment, it explains the reflected symbol in more detail